# Empathy new message field does not wrap to next line, but increases the window width instead

Tags: 11.04, empathy, irc

I'm using Empathy as an IRC client. Not sure if this affects other protocols as well. When I start typing new message in the field on the bottom of the conversation window, and the message becomes too long to fit on one line, the window starts to grow horizontally instead of the message wrapping to next line. This is very annoying when typing long message, as the window quickly grows beyond the screen edge.

Don't know if this is a bug or a really obscure feature. Shall I report a bug, or is there a setting somewhere to change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was (is) a bug on empathy that is described here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+bug/509866

I am not sure if that is the same issue you are having but there is a workaround described on the bug report for it.

Have a look and gl ;)

Comment: Cheers man, the workaround works for me.